# second level activation problem with redrawing grid (game logic)

Tags: javascript

I'm building a 2D js pacman with a key/door for second level. The idea is to have an ability to get to next level after grabbing the key. The grid is updated once pacman gets to the door. Game data is an array with two grids in it. What is the best way to redraw the gird?
Also can anybody suggest good resources for creating ghosts? Thank you in advance.

level change logic

```
let level = 0;

let grid = gameData[0]

function levelChange() {
    console.log(grid[pacman.y][pacman.x] === grid[door.y][door.x])
    if (grid[pacman.y][pacman.x] === grid[door.y][door.x]) {
        grid = gameData[1];
        level += 1;
    }
    console.log(level)
    console.log(grid)
}

let map;

let pacman = {
    x: 6,
    y: 4,
    direction: 'right'
};

let door = {
    x: 11,
    y: 8,
}
```

drawing grid

```
function drawMap() {
    map = document.createElement('div');
    // console.log(grid)
    let tiles = createTiles(grid);
    tiles.forEach(tile => { 
        map.appendChild(tile);
    });
    document.getElementById('body').appendChild(map)
    // document.body.appendChild(map);
}
```

calling the level change

```
function setupKeyboardControls() {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
        // console.log(e.keyCode);
        if (e.keyCode === 37) {
            moveLeft();
        } else if (e.keyCode === 38) {
            moveUp();
        } else if (e.keyCode === 39) {
            moveRight();
        } else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
            moveDown();
        }
        eraseMap();
        drawMap();
        screenScore();
        doorUnlock();
        levelChange();
    });
}

function main() {
    drawMap();
    setupKeyboardControls();
}

main();
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

just had to move drawMap/eraseMap to the bottom of setupKeyboardControls()